# How can I read the json in a POST/PUT in a RestEasy interceptor for validation

Tags: java, validation, jax-rs, resteasy, interceptor

I'm trying to use a RestEasy interceptor to validate a JSON object coming over for insertion or updating in a PUT/POST. Given that all I have access to by implementing PreProcessInterceptor is this method:

```
@Override
public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethod method) throws Failure, WebApplicationException
{
    return null;
}
```

Is it possible to read the JSON from the request w/o affecting later unmarshalling when my resource gets called?

Also, is possible to do this validation in a more efficient way?  It seemed that the interceptor makes for cleaner code by not cluttering my resource w/ a bunch of logic, but it may result in overhead of unmarshalling the JSON twice.  I'm open to any suggestions..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary usecase for the interceptors are not validation. I would suggest that you either validate your input in your JAX-RS annotated methods, or check out the [bean validation integration](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.6.Final/userguide/html_single/#d4e2148) they provide.